# "look for ways" vs "look for the ways"

Tags: grammar, articles

Do we need article in the following sentence:

> We always look for **the** ways to increase our total gain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you want to say, if you look for **the ways** then you're looking for all of them, whereas if you're looking for **ways** you're looking for **some ways** but not necessarily all of them.

Comment: To build off this, an example would be "let's look for the ways mice get into the house".  You want to find all of them.  "Let's look for ways to get across this river."  You only need one that works.

Comment: Thank you very much!